# IJCADのVBAでSaveASコマンド実施時にダイアログが表示されてしまう

Tags: vba, ijcad

AutoCAD VBAで作成したDXF一括変換モジュールをIJCAD 2019に移行しています。
VBAからSaveASを利用してDXFに変換しようとしているのですが、コマンド実行中にファイル保存ダイアログが表示されてしまい、一括変換ができません。

AutoCADでは特に問題なく動作していました。IJCADではAPI処理中のダイアログの表示について、設定等あるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

表示されているダイアログが、図面がDXF形式で保存されているためDWG形式で保存するかどうかを確認するダイアログの場合は、残念ながらこのダイアログを非表示にさせる方法はありません。

最近のAutoCADもこのダイアログが表示されるのは仕様なので、IJCADも仕様をそれに合わせているのだと思います。

[AutoCADの動きについての記事](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/kA230000000th5e.html)

IJCADでこのダイアログを出さずに図面をDXFに変換するのであれば、SAVEASを利用するのではなくDXFOUTを利用した方が良いと思います。
ただ、IJCADではDXFOUTを実行するとDBMODの値が変更されるようなので、DXF書き出し後に図面を上書き保存することで、警告ダイアログを出さずに複数の図面をDXFに一括変換できると思います。